# Excel file is being used by another process in the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am importing an Excel file with the code

```
public partial class GeneralVehicle : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FilePath;
        string Extension;

        if (Session["FilePath"] != null && Session["Extension"] != null)
        {
            FilePath = Convert.ToString(Session["FilePath"]);
            Extension = Convert.ToString(Session["Extension"]);

            Import_To_Grid(FilePath, Extension);
        }
    }

    private void Import_To_Grid(string FilePath, string Extension)
    {
        string conStr = "";
        switch (Extension)
        {

            case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'";

                break;

            case ".xlsx": //Excel 07

                conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0}; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'";

                break;

        }

        conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, "Yes");
        OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
        OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;



        //Get the name of First Sheet
        connExcel.Open();
        DataTable dtExcelSchema;
        dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        connExcel.Close();



        //Read Data from First Sheet

        connExcel.Open();
        cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "] where Print = 'No' ";
        oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
        oda.Fill(dt);
        connExcel.Close();



        //Bind Data to GridView

        //  GridView1.Caption = Path.GetFileName(FilePath);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

The excel is uploaded at the first time, but when I try to upload the same excel again it gives me error that.

> The process cannot access the file 'D:\INETPUB\VHOSTS\rajseva.com\httpdocs\Files\passfile_generalvh.xlsx' because it is being used by another process

Please help.

Thank You.

Comment: Did you try wrapping the lines that use Excel inside..
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
{
   ....
}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally changing

```
        connExcel.Open();
        cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "] where Print = 'No' ";
        oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
        oda.Fill(dt);
        connExcel.Close();
```

To

```
    connExcel.Open();
    cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "] where Print = 'No' ";
    oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
    oda.Fill(dt);
    connExcel.Close();
    connExcel.Dispose();  //adding this and
    cmdExcel.Dispose();   // this
```

Solved the problem.

Comment: You should consider using `using` blocks instead. If there is an exception, the file will not get released and you may experience the same error.

Comment: do you mean exception handling?

Comment: Sort of - read the docs on `using` to know how it relates to exception handling. Right now, if there is an exception in the query, `Dispose()` will not be called and your file will not be released in a timely manner.